# Table structure for entity versioning

Tags: mysql, database-design

For an assignment I have to build an application that is able to store tests. Every test has to be validated by a a different user when created or updated. When it has been validated by an user, the test gets an expiry date of the last time it was validated plus 2 years.

Everytime a test gets updated, it creates a new version: `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc. This versioning information is stored in the `test_versions` table.

The tests itself are all stored in the same `tests` table with a foreign key to the `test_versions` table (`version_id`)`table. The`test` table consists of multiple many-to-many relations with joining-tables. For the sake of simplicity, I didn't include these in my table definition.

```
create table tests
(
    id                  int auto_increment   primary key,
    name                varchar(255)         not null,
    description         varchar(2048)        not null,
    version_id          int                  not null,
    is_active           tinyint(1) default 1 null comment,
    created_at          timestamp            null,
    updated_at          timestamp            null
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Every new test is made with a new revision. The `tests` table has an `version_id` column. This is referring to the `test_versions` table which has the following columns:

- `version_id`
- `description`
- `original_version_id` (The test where this version is made off)
- `tag` (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc.)
- `is_current_version` (An indicator if it's the test's current version)
- `expiry_date` (The expiry date of the current version, after this date, the test would not be showing).

It's possible to have unlimited versions for every test.

Now the problem is that when a new test is created, a new version should also be created in the `test_versions` table. This is not possible in the current structure since every new record in the `test_versions` table needs an `test_id`.

Dropping, or not working with foreign keys would not be an option.

**Questions**

- How can I create the table structure in a way that I can still have unlimited versions without having the foreign key problems? How does the StackExchange site do it for example?
- In my structure, every new test needs a version. Can this be done any better or is it efficient to split data over multiple tables?
- Could there be another table structure for not working with these FK's in both directions?
- Is it efficiënt to store more versions in the same `tests` table? Is there any other/better way?

Comment: I'm confused.  Conceptually, I'd expect you to have a `Tests` table, with one record per test, a `TestVersions` table with one record per version of a test (starting with v1, when a test is created), and a `TestApprovals` table, dependent on the `TestVersions` table.  It looks like the `tests` table for which you've given a schema is the second table; is that right?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades         The `test` table consists of all the information concerened about the test itself. The `test_versions` about the versioning information yeah. The test approval table isn't important at this moment.

Comment: Ah, so the `test.version_id` field isn't the version ID, it's an FK to the current record for that test in the `test_versions` table?  That could probably be renamed.  I'm not sure I see the problem, though; as long as you insert into `test` first, it's easy to create a record in `test_versions` at the same time, either in a sproc or a trigger.  That'll ensure that you never have a record in the one table without a record in the other (except for in the middle of the transaction, which is why we have transactions).

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Exactly. `test.version_id` refers to `test_versions.id`But since every `test` needs a `test_version`, for storing it's version information, the `test` record can't be inserted first. I don't understand anything and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference is to handle this with a stored procedure rather than a trigger, but that's an option if you have a lot of legacy code running unwrapped `INSERT`s.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTest (Name VARCHAR(255), Description VARCHAR(2048))
    BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO test (name, description, version_id) VALUES (Name, Description, 0);
    DECLARE TestID INT;
    SET TestID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO test_versions (test_id) VALUES (TestID);
    DECLARE TestVersionID INT;
    SET TestVersionID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    UPDATE test SET version_id = TestVersionID WHERE id = TestID;

    COMMIT;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Apologies if I screwed up the MySQL syntax, I've been working in MS SQL 90% of the time for the past ten years.

Note that this code temporarily sets the value of `version_id` to zero, to satisfy the FK.  You'd need a dummy record in `test_versions` with such an ID.  However, the field is updated before the transaction commits, so no queries should ever see this value.

---

Edit: if you are really concerned about the INSERT performance of this sproc, you could simplify it by giving `test_version` a composite PK on `test_id` and `version_id`, where `version_id` is a sequence (starting at 1) for each test.  You would need to retrieve only one `AUTO_INCREMENT` value:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTest (Name VARCHAR(255), Description VARCHAR(2048))
    BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO test (name, description, version_id) VALUES (Name, Description, 1);
    DECLARE TestID INT;
    SET TestID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO test_versions (test_id, version_id) VALUES (TestID, 1);

    COMMIT;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see, `version_id` can be assumed to be 1 for the first record, so there's no need to UPDATE `test`.  You also don't need a dummy record #0 in `test_version`.  However, the broader PK would make indices on `test_version` slightly bigger.  Using a narrow integer for `version_id` would help.

Comment: Looks good, is this the most efficiënt table structure for my use case though?

Comment: *Most* efficient is, realistically, an impossible goal.  However, I see very little overhead with this design.  Unless you're running thousands of inserts per second, I doubt that this procedure is likely to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Well, I don't like the needed FK in both directions. I only would be able to insert records using the transactions. Isn't there an alternative for that?

Comment: Bidirectional FKs are a little sticky; at times, I'm happy to not use them, in a reporting database (they're indispensable in a transactional database).  If you drop the FK in `test`, or the entire `test.version_id` field, you won't need the dummy record, but that's a pretty small gain.

Comment: So there is not really a different way then using these transactions besides using 2 FK's in one of the two tables? Can't I have a second db table of old test versions?

Comment: Sure.  For any given group *n* of DBAs or database developers, you'll probably get n+1 possible solutions.  You could have a single table with all versions, one of which is marked "current"; a new record would be created with a single INSERT operation, but your table would be big and denormalized.  You could have one table of current versions, and a second table with old versions.  You can look up "slowly changing dimension" for various strategies on managing this.  I've offered one solution which is simple to implement and works with your schema as described, but you could re-engineer more.